Auto populate cell with lowest date from two other cells
I need to populate a cell with the lowest date from 2 cells.
I need to populate cell J23 with the lowest date that appears in either cell H23 or G23. This will need to be able to be done in each cell from J23 to J85.
Not sure on the code required.

Does this answer your question? How to compare two dates and take one that is smaller? e.g MIN for DATE

The MIN function would work. If you have a date in G23 and another in H23, the formula =MIN(H23, G23) will return the earlier of those two dates.
Then extend the J23 cell down to line 85.
